# How to bind data to DataRelation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datasource

I have the following code to create two Binding Sources. The first one if filled with a master table, and the second one with child table based on a relation.

```
    Dim DataSet As New DataSet
    Dim BindingSource1 As New BindingSource
    Dim BindingSource2 As New BindingSource

    Dim DataTable1 As DataTable = GetDT1()
    Dim DataTable2 As DataTable = GetDT2()

    DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable1)
    DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable2)

    Dim Rel As DataRelation = New DataRelation("R", DataSet.Tables("DT1").Columns("C1"), DataSet.Tables("DT2").Columns("C1"), True)
    DataSet.Relations.Add(Rel)

    BindingSource1.DataSource = DataSet
    BindingSource1.DataMember = "DT1"

    BindingSource2.DataSource = DataSet
    BindingSource2.DataMember = "R"
```

where GetDT1 and GetDT2 are as follows :

```
Public Function GetDT1() As DataTable
    Dim DT As New DataTable("DT1")

    DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C1"))

    Dim R As DataRow = DT.NewRow

    R("C1") = 1
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    R = DT.NewRow
    R("C1") = 2
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    R = DT.NewRow
    R("C1") = 3
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    Return DT
End Function

Public Function GetDT2() As DataTable
    Dim DT As New DataTable("DT2")

    DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C1"))
    DT.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("C2"))

    Dim R As DataRow = DT.NewRow

    R("C1") = 1
    R("C2") = "A"
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    R = DT.NewRow
    R("C1") = 1
    R("C2") = "B"
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    R = DT.NewRow
    R("C1") = 2
    R("C2") = "Coucou"
    DT.Rows.Add(R)

    Return DT
End Function
```

When I run the code, I have an error in the line : **BindingSource2.DataMember = "R"**. It says :

**DataMember property 'R' cannot be found on the DataSource.**

Does anyone know what's wrong with my code please ?

Cheers,

Comment: [How to: Create a Master/Detail Form Using Two Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/create-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews). TLDR version: `BindingSource2.DataSource=BindingSource1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer :

```
Dim DataSet As New DataSet
Dim BindingSource1 As New BindingSource
Dim BindingSource2 As New BindingSource

Dim DataTable1 As DataTable = GetDT1()
Dim DataTable2 As DataTable = GetDT2()

DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable1)
DataSet.Tables.Add(DataTable2)

Dim Rel As DataRelation = New DataRelation("R", DataSet.Tables("DT1").Columns("C1"), DataSet.Tables("DT2").Columns("C1"), True)
DataSet.Relations.Add(Rel)

BindingSource1.DataSource = DataSet
BindingSource1.DataMember = "DT1"

BindingSource2.DataSource = BindingSource1
BindingSource2.DataMember = "R"
```